# Does Google App Inventor work on AT&T phones?

Tags: android

I am planning on purchasing the Motorola Atrix 4G for AT&T. As is, you will not be able to side load apps without using [Sideload Wonder](http://www.androidcentral.com/sideload-android-apps-all-you-want-sideload-wonder-machine) or something similar.

Does Google App Inventor work with AT&T phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it should. The preferred way to work with Google App inventor is through the use of the usb cable anyway (forget Sideload Wonder, Google App inventor is a very different animal, it's not like your standard Android developer tools at all).

The reason you'll want to use the usb cable (the one that will come with your phone) is because any changes you make to the blocks you're editing will appear immediately on your phone, and the rapid feedback you get from App Inventor (as opposed to ADT/adb/Eclipse) is absolutely phenomenal.

That being said, are you really sure you want to learn App Inventor? If you're serious about developing for Android, you'll want to use the more traditional Android developer tools.

App Inventor doesn't give you access to the source (to them, the visual blocks are the source), and even if they wanted to give you access to the source, it would just look like partially compiled Scheme/LISP anyway. So App Inventor is a great tool for kids/teenagers/beginners/teachers/hobbyists, it's a great tool for learning how to program in general, it's even a better and more sophisticated tool than most of the most traditional developer tools I've seen, but don't count on it if you really intend to program on Android for professional reasons.

Comment: I don't need to program in Android for professional reasons. Looking to use App Inventor as a hobbyist and if I wanted to sit down and do a complete end-to-end app I would work through the source in Eclipse and such.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you'll be able to export your apps from App Inventor and sideload them manually each time using Sideload Wonder. It would seem silly to me to release a phone that wouldn't work with developer tools, but there are plenty of examples of AT&T being a bit silly when it comes to openness.